# recv() keep returning the same data

Tags: python, sockets, select, python-3.x, recv

I'm working on a simple asynchronous HTTP proxy.
i wrote this function to receive all data (since i don't know the specific size of received data):

```
def recvall(sock):
    data = b""
    while True:
        r, w, e = select.select([sock], [], [], 1)
        if r:
            data+= sock.recv(65535)
            if not data: # if empty
                break 
        else:
            break
    return data
```

this piece of code works fine, but during my tests, i noticed that the loop never ends and keeps receiving the same data again and again (specifically, "301 moved permanently...").
This is very weird behavior of recv().
Probably this is not the best way to receive all data from sockets, but i can't think of any explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following lines:

```
data += sock.recv(65535)
if not data: # if empty
    break
```

should be changed:

```
chunk = sock.recv(65535)
if not chunk:
    break
data += chunk
```

Otherwise it will check accumulated data, instead of the data just received; causing endless loop if there was any data received.